# c++ initialized specified for non-virtual method

Tags: c++

I have a.h as shown below

```
class A
{
public:
    void doSomething()=0;
};
```

Then i have b.h as shown below

```
#include "a.h"

class b: public A
{
public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

I am just trying to check for syntax errors by trying to compile headers such as 
`g++ -c a.h b.h`

and i get below errror

`a.h:4: error: initializer specified for non-virtual method 'void A::doSomething()'`

What does this error means?

Comment: It needs to be declared virtual: `virtual void doSomething() = 0;`

Comment: Also, why are you compiling headers?  That's weird.  Are you new to structuring projects in C++?

Answer (score 22):

A member function can only be declared abstract (`= 0`) if it is virtual. Add the `virtual` keyword to the function declaration in the base class (in class `A`).

Prior to C++11, it was also good practice to repeat `virtual` in the declaration of the derived class member function, although it's technically not necessary there (as the rule is "once virtual, always virtual").

C++11 introduced the `override` keyword which can should used when overriding a virtual member function, to make the code safe against future changes (i.e. if the base function changes signature, the derived code will fail to compile instead of silently becoming wrong). Whether to also include `virtual` when `override` is present is up to personal taste/project coding standards. I consider it unnecessary and omit it, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: The error message could have just said that. Typical that the error message is wholly incomprehensible unless you already know what it means.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is exactly what the compiler says it is.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething()=0; // virtual keyword needed
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It means that `A`'s do something isn't virtual, but you are trying to make it pure virtual.